# Menu items at right (margin-left issues)

Tags: css, menu, alignment

I'm building [this site](http://ffio.it/bozzasettembrini/), as you can see I moved the nav menu to the left. If you hover the mouse on any item "Home" / "L'istituto" / "Infanzia/Primaria" (etc) the child items are shown to the right. Everything's ok except that the `position:relative;` `left:130px` on `.main-navigation li ul li` a make the underneath items non-clickable (because there is the block there, moved to the right because of the `left:130px`. How can I have the underneath items still clickable? Thanks in advance.

P.S.: If I try with a `z-index: 999999` on `.main-navigation li a`, `.main-navigation li` I can't reach the child items anymore (except the first one).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I set this and worked :)

```
.main-navigation li ul {
margin: 0 0 0 200px;
position: absolute;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to optimise the width of the vertical navigation bar.

Comment: Try setting width of the ul inside the menu-default-container to be somewhere around 30%. It works for me.